# Pagination In Doctrine 2, ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, doctrine, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement pagination, using the latest version of Doctrine:
https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html?highlight=doctrine%20dql%20pagination

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT b,pb
        FROM BookApi\Entity\Book b
        LEFT JOIN b.publisher pb        
        ')->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(10);
$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);    
$this->totalResults = count($paginator);
```

The **count** I get returned with the paginator is correct.
However the getQuery does not give me ten results. It returns 5.

```
$output = $paginator->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: @ocramius shows how to do it here in his Doctrine/ZF2 tutorial (worth a read in itself) -> http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment above, this worked for me.
I had to add the hydration mode

```
$book = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
     SELECT b,pb
     FROM BookApi\Entity\Book b
     LEFT JOIN b.publisher pb   
')->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$paginator = new Paginator(
     new DoctrinePaginator(new ORMPaginator($book))
);

$paginator
        ->setCurrentPageNumber(0)
        ->setItemCountPerPage(10);
```